# Is there a proof of this process? Finding polynomial equations from a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I'm guessing it has been but I can't find it anywhere. Would love to find a name for this process and a write up of it.

To start I know how to find the equation of a polynomial of N degree with N-1 points.

However in grade school I found an interesting property to do the same thing if you have a series of X values
$$X = \{a, a+1, a+2,...,a+n\}, a\in\mathbb{N}$$

and the corresponding Y values

$$Y = \{f(x)\}, \forall x\in X$$

You can find the polynomial

$$ f(x) = ax^n + bx^{n-1}...+ z $$

By constructing a pyramid of differences like so it will eventually become a static $n!a$ at the top level (sorry formatting a pyramid is hard)
$$n!a$$
$$f(a+1)-f(a) \quad\quad f(a+2)-f(a+1)\quad f(a+2)-f(a+2)...\quad f(a+n)-f(a+n-1)$$
$$f(a) \quad\qquad f(a+1) \quad\qquad f(a+2) \quad\qquad f(a+3)\quad\qquad...\quad\qquad f(a+n-1) \quad\qquad f(a+n)$$

Then once you have this value you know the equation $$f(x)=ax^n$$ so you can substract it from every value of your series and build a new smaller pyramid to find $$f(x)=bx^{n-1}$$ and so on until you are left with the final constant $z$ and you have found the entire equation.

Example given the set of $X = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $y = \{2,12,36,80,150\}$

You can make a pyramid like so:
$$6 \quad 6$$
$$14 \quad 20 \quad 26$$
$$10 \quad 24 \quad 44 \quad 70$$
$$2 \quad 12 \quad 36 \quad 80 \quad 150$$

So you know the polynomial is degree 3 and $a=1$ you can subtract $f(x)=x^3$ from the given set of $Y$ values and repeat the process until you have no terms left and reconstruct the equation. The next pyramid:
$$2 \quad 2 \quad 2$$
$$3 \quad 5 \quad 7 \quad 9$$
$$1 \quad 4 \quad 9 \quad 16 \quad 25$$

And find $f(x)=x^2$ and the new $Y$ values are $\{0,0..0\}$ so you know you are done and the original equation is $f(x)=x^3+x^2$

This is obviously a very cumbersome process the higher the degree and the larger the number of terms in the polynomial but I have never heard it being formally described before. So, any name for this process or a write up of it? Also, sorry again for formatting.

I really like this process because it's easy for grade school equations and it is recursive. It also brings in suspicious factorials for some reason I have not figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known fact. You should be happy to have figured it by yourself.

You can find this and some generalization if you study [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference).

This is an hint of the explanation:

If you compute $(x+1)^n-x^n$ with the binomial formula then the result is of the form $n\cdot x^{n-1}+\cdots$, because the leading terms $x^n$ cancel out.

Now, if you take consider a further step in difference, the leading term will be  $n$ times the first differences of the terms $x^{n-1}$, but this is, similarly as before, $(n-1)x^{n-2}$, so the leading term the second differences will be $n(n-1)x^{n-2}$.  Repeating this up to $n$ steps you will obtain $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 2\cdot1\cdot x^0$, i.e., $n!$.

This is the underlying reason why factorials appear, clearly one has to work out all the details to see why this holds for general polynomials and general equidistant points etc.etc.

Comment: I understand if this is well known but is there a proof somewhere showing that this works? Even googling for finite differences and polynomials isn't returning very much other than one quick write up showing this process.